# Build pojo from multiple sql queries results using jooq

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

Usual way is to map a single query result to a class e.g.

```
List<MyPojo> p = ctx.fetch("select * from table...").into(MyPojo.class);
```

But what if I want to build a pojo based on several queries results? Note that some of pojo fields are objects.

```
class MyPojo{
  String field1 - query1
  int field2 - query1
  List<SomeClass> field3 - query2
  SomeClass2 - query3
  ...
}
```

Will really appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Why not use generated code and build a single type safe query using the powerful mapping features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obviously map your code manually by running several queries and assembling the results into your result type individually (there's no automatic way to do this in jOOQ). But much better than that, just use

- [jOOQ's code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/) (things will get so much better with that!)
- [`MULTISET`](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/), [nested records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/), and [ad-hoc converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/)

An example would be:

```java
List<MyPojo> result =
ctx.select(
      T.FIELD1,
      T.FIELD2,
      multiset(
        select(U.COL1, U.COL2)
        .from(U)
        .where(U.T_ID.eq(T.ID))
      ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(SomeClass::new))),
      field(
        select(row(X.COL1, X.COL2).mapping(SomeClass2::new))
        .from(X)
        .where(X.T_ID.eq(T.ID))
      ))
   .from(T)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(MyPojo::new));
```

All of this is completely type safe and not using any reflection. All you need for those constructor references to work is add the constructor to your `MyPojo`, or make it a `record`, instead:

```java
record MyPojo(
  String field1,
  int field2,
  List<SomeClass> field3,
  SomeClass2 field4
) {}
```